# android:layout_height="wrap_content" problem after updating Android Studio

Tags: android-layout

After updating Android Studio to 4.0.1 the parameter `android:layout_height=` doesn't accept more than `30dp`, Does anyone know why?

I have already verified if was any parameter which possiblely was blocking this layout increasing, but I can't figure it out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

can u try  edit from xml file???

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_phone"
            android:layout_width="35"
            android:layout_height="35"
            />
```

Comment: i'm sorry a made a mistaken, i set android:layout_marginTop="100dp" and a android:layout_marginbottom="100dp" at the same time the were limiting the android:layout_height="35".